# Increasing Text Field Length on Package Upgrade

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, upgrade

I currently have a released managed package with a custom object that has a Text field of length 10. Can I increase this length in a future release of the package, and if so, are there are any impacts to existing records for that object?

Comment: An old blog post on the subject [Modifying custom fields after a managed package is released](https://force201.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/modifying-custom-fields-after-a-managed-package-is-released/). We've done increases before. Not sure how/if truncation warnings are presented for decreases - never had to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_attributes.htm) says field length is developer editable and confirms its not locked .So you can definitely increase the length .Increasing the length will have no impact

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the ISVForce Guide, the following changes can be made to custom fields after a package is released:

[image]